# Error playing sounds in PsychoPy: Could not convert string to float

Tags: python, string, audio, wav, psychopy

I am having problems playing sounds in PsychoPy, and I don't know why. 
I get this error message: `Could not convert string to float: Sounds/dog.wav`

Here is my code:

```
# Grounding of Words Experiment #

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Import libraries
import re
import glob
from psychopy import sound, visual, event, data, core, gui # imports a module for visual presentation and one for controlling events like key presses
import ppc

Sounds=["Sounds/dog.wav", "Sounds/dog.mp3"]

#from psychopy import prefs
#prefs.general['audioLib'] = ['pygame']

sound_name = sound.Sound(Sounds)

sound_name.play()

core.quit()
```

Comment: My psychopy version is 1.82.01, I dont know if this makes any difference.

Comment: does it work with `Sound/dog.mp3` ?

Comment: are you sure `Sound()` needs list of files, not single name ? `sound.Sound("Sounds/dog.wav")` or `sound.Sound(Sounds[0])`

Answer (score 2):

Your `Sounds` variable is a list containing two strings. The `sound.Sound()` function expects just a single string to define the audio file to use. I can't bring up the API at the moment, but I guess if the function gets more than one argument, it expects the second to be a numeric value (like a duration, perhaps). Hence it is complaining that you have passed it a string (the second filename) when it was expecting a number there.

So you need to specify one particular sound file rather than the entire list, so just a single value is passed to the `sound.Sound()` function. 
e.g. refer to it by index:

```
sound_name = sound.Sound(Sounds[0])
```

Or feed them one at a time to the function by iterating through the list:

```
for sound_file in Sounds:
    sound_name = sound.Sound(sound_file)
    sound_name.play()
```

And maybe think about making your variable names more precisely match their contents, to avoid confusion. e.g. in your code, `Sounds` is actually a list of sound (file) names, while `sound_name` is not the name of a sound, but an actual `Sound` object. i.e. Sound objects can be played, stopped, etc, whereas names are just strings, that can be printed, concatenated, used as a file path, etc.